# Need Guidance on Marketing Cloud Sync and Journey Builder Set up

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, sync

I need some Architecture / Data Modeling help in regards to Journey builder and the CRM
 
I am brining new Customers into the SFMC via a Salesforce Data Event in Journey Builder, for a welcome journey. I am leveraging the Lead object.  
 
There is a custom Customer_ID field in the Lead Object which I want to use as my unique identifier for a customer.
 
Via the sync, i can set that up to be the Contact_Key in my contact Model.   But in Journey Builder, I am pretty sure the system sets the Lead_ID to be Subscriber_ID. I dont see how to set the Contact Key to be "ID" from lead.
 
I fear i am not getting my complete view of sends for new Leads.

But how do I tie the sends in the Journey to the contact model?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood correctly: you use marketing cloud connect to leverage a journey based on the lead object and want to use a custom field (I assume it to be an external identifier type in CRM) on the lead object as unique key (aka contact key) in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Correct - well re-stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilising any field for SFMC Contact Key, other than standard record ID is to my knowledge not possible. Any injections using Salesforce Data Entry Event, will use Salesforce Record ID - this is true regardless of leads, contacts or person accounts.

Your Customer_ID can still be passed on to SFMC using Journey Data, but using the standard Journey Builder integration is not possible. You could potentially write custom trigger in Sales Cloud, calling an API Entry Event in Journey Builder, passing Customer_ID as Contact Key. Here you will not only miss out on the ease of configuration which is provided by Salesforce Data Entry Event, but also miss tracking being sent back to Individual Email Results in Sales Cloud - since these only work with the default IDs.

Comment: thank you @lukas Lunow  

So in my scenario, since JB will automatically use the SFDC Lead Object Record ID as the Contact Key,  my best path is to stick with that and create a DE to hold the relationship of that Record ID (Now Contact_Key) to the unique ID field the customer would like to use/reference.  Do you agree ?